# How to format a date string with ionic2

Tags: angular, date, ionic2

I'll make this concise. I have the following object:

```
obj = {date: 2017-04-05T17:48:20.084Z}
```

How do i format j.date ? I've tried the following code bellow but it does work

```
<ion-item *ngFor='let j of obj'>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY">{{j.date}}</ion-datetime>
 </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/), you shouldn’t place `j.date` inside the `ion-datetime` element, but you should bind to it using `ngModel`. The code:

```html
<ion-item *ngFor='let j of obj'>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="j.date"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Thankyou sir, i wasn't aware you could use ngModel in that way